# Html text stacking on top of div instead of vertically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following set of divs inside a div that I want to stack vertically. However the text in the last div seems to be stacking on top of the div in the second section when I wanted them to stack vertically so the text in the third dive appears below the graph. I'm not sure why `display: flex` and  `flex-direction: column;` aren't making the divs behave as intended.

```js
var width = 710, height = 710;
var margin = {top: -20, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 40};

d3.select("canvas").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);

var canvas = d3.select("canvas");

var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

var svg = d3.select("#app")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var xAxis = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([-1.5, 1.5])
    .range([0, width]);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xAxis));

var yAxis = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([-1.5, 1.5])
    .range([height, 0]);

svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yAxis));
```

```css
p {
    font-size: 2.7vmin;
    line-height: 1.8; 
    text-align: left; 
    /*color: white;  */
}
button {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 2rem;
}

.simBlock {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

svg {
    position: absolute;
}

canvas {
    position: absolute;
}

#section {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="simBlock">
    <div id="section">
        <button type="button" id="pauseButton">Play/Pause</button>
        <button type="button" id="resetButton">Reset</button>
    </div>
    <div id="section">
        <canvas></canvas>
        <svg id="app"></svg>
    </div>
    <div id="section">
        <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Dolores, minus deleniti. Quia consectetur laboriosam aperiam inventore, suscipit id iusto neque culpa? Perferendis mollitia corporis saepe aspernatur enim necessitatibus voluptatibus earum.
        </p>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: ID's should be unique on a page. You can change that to a class.

Comment: You need to get rid of the `position: absolute;` from `canvas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments removing `position: absolute` from canvas does the trick